# com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try Firebase push notification in a separate Android studio project and it
 work fin but when I integrate it in a existing project I had this problem .

Error : 
 D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.

Depend:

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

       compile project(':library')
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'


        compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'


        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implementation instead of compile. Also, make sure you have implemented Firebase Auth in your project.